# iPhone - How To Turn off Screen & Keep a video playing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I have a youtube video running in my iPhone app.... How can I make it to where the user can hit the lock button but still be able to listen to the video, but just not see it?

So basically you have a Youtube video playing in my iPhone application. How can the user turn of the screen but still keep the audio from going out as well?

Is this possible if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible if your device is not jailbroken. Apple doesn't allow app developers to publish such apps due to their strict rules. You can have a look at the Apple's Human Interface Guidelines [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf)

If your device is jailbroken, then there might be some tweaks in cydia for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in Apple's developer documentation by searching for "Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks".

Comment: I didn't find anything and I searched exactly what you said.